# Working with EAV model in Propel

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel, entity-attribute-value

I have a database with a EAV structure, having this tables :

```
Entity (id, name)
Attribute (id, name)
AttributeValue(fk_id_entity, fk_id_attribute, value)
```

What I want to do is translate this following query in Propel:

```
SELECT entity.name, avx.value, avy.value
FROM Entity entity
INNER JOIN AttributeValue avx ON (avx.fk_id_entity = entity.id 
AND avx.name = 'X')
INNER JOIN AttributeValue avy ON (avy.fk_id_entity = entity.id 
AND avy.name = 'Y')
```

Any idea how could I do this in Popel?
Thank you!

LE: The ideea is that each entity has two attributes X and Y, and I would like to display a list of all entities along with their X and Y attributes.

Comment: Hmm... not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, can you post some sample data and expected output? That might help us create the proper Propel (and SQL) structure.

Comment: @jakerella Thank you for your answer! I updated the question and got rid of those "xvalue", and "yvalue" - actually it should be "value" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it actually worked is the following:

```
$result = Entity_EntityQuery::create()
->withColumn('alias1.value', 'xvalue')
->withColumn('alias2.value', 'yvalue')
->innerjoinValue('alias1')
->useValueQuery('alias1')
->filterbyFkAttribute('x attribute id')
->endUse()
->innerjoinValue('alias1')
->useValueQuery('alias1')
->filterbyFkAttribute('y attribute id')
->endUse()
...//conditions
->find()
```

Thanks everybody for viewing and replying!

Answer (score 2):

So here's one way to just replicate what you have in the SQL, but as I mention in my comment, there may be a more efficient way to do it. If you provide an answer to my comment question above I'll see if I can improve this answer.

First, you will need a [cross reference table](http://propelorm.org/documentation/04-relationships.html#many-to-many-relationships) in your schema. I'll assume that you do, and that it is called `AttributeValue`. Then you add your joins to the `EntityQuery` and add additional conditions.

**Unfortunately, it looks like there may be a bug in Propel that will prevent the code below from producing the proper SQL.**

```
$results = EntityQuery::create()
  ->join('Entity.AttributeValue avx')
  ->join('avx.Attribute xa')
  ->addJoinCondition('xa', 'xa.name = ?', 'X')
  ->join('Entity.AttributeValue avy')
  ->join('avy.Attribute ya')
  ->addJoinCondition('ya', 'ya.name = ?', 'Y')
  ->select(array('entity.name', 'avx.value', 'avy.value'));
```

This **should** produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT entity.name AS 'entity.name', 
       avx.value AS 'avx.value', 
       avy.value AS 'avy.value'
  FROM `entity` 
    INNER JOIN `attribute_value` `avx` ON (entity.id = avx.entity_id) 
    INNER JOIN `attribute` `ax` ON (avx.attribute_id = ax.id AND ax.name =  'X') 
    INNER JOIN `attribute_value` `avy` ON (entity.id = avy.entity_id) 
    INNER JOIN `attribute` `ay` ON (avy.attribute_id = ay.id AND ay.name =  'Y')
```

Unfortunately, this is produced instead:

```
SELECT entity.name AS 'entity.name', 
       aatribute_value.value AS 'avx.value', 
       aatribute_value.value AS 'avx.value'
  FROM `entity` 
    INNER JOIN `attribute_value` `avx` ON (entity.id = avx.entity_id) 
    INNER JOIN `attribute` `ax` ON (avx.attribute_id = ax.id AND attribute.name =  'X') 
    INNER JOIN `attribute_value` `avy` ON (entity.id = avy.entity_id) 
    INNER JOIN `attribute` `ay` ON (avy.attribute_id = ay.id AND attribute.name =  'Y')
```

(The problem is the `SELECT` line and the `INNER JOIN` on `attribute` which uses `attribute.name =  'X'` instead of the proper `ax.name =  'X'`.)

So, you could run the **correct** SQL using a manual query, or wait for the bug to be fixed (I'll try to write up an [issue on guthub](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues) and work on a fix.)

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Information gathered from the [Propel documentation on joining tables](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#joining-tables).